# A good way to read data from a text file and fill the inputs on the page

Tags: javascript, web, format

I want to let user upload a text file, after that the page will read the data from this file and fill the forms, textareas, selects, etc. 
Right now, I'm using javascript FileReader class to upload a file and then read it line by line:

```
var fr=new FileReader(); 
fr.onload=function()
{ 
   fillForms(fr.result);
} 
fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
```

So the most basic format is something like this:

```
key1,value1
key2,value2
...
keyN,valueN
```

Where 'key' equals to the id of an html element, 'value' - value of this element. 
The problems I have right now are:
1) value can have non-alphabetic characters such as comma, period etc. How do I distinguish between a comma in value and one that separates key and value.
2) value can be a list of object. For example, if there is a list that has 3 objects, then I want to display 3 paragraphs. Each paragraph will have several textfields displaying values stored in the fields of the object.

What is a good format for a text file? I can try using JSON format, if so how do I parse it? Also, is there a more user-friendly format that I can implement?

Comment: I have a code that can be used to separate the values in a csv but by commas. I can share that if you want, but I dont think that'll work for you here if your key column includes those as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it might be easier to use php here. A .php file will provide you an easier method to read a file and parse information from that file. To open a file and simply print its contents, you can use this:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("your_file", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("your_file"));
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

However, there is a lot of opportunities using php. Here is a link that will teach you about how you can parse data should you choose to go down the php route:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp